# Что делать с легаси кодом в обучающих материалах

Tags: ios, objective-c

Посматриваю видео по objective'у и бывает проскакивают устаревшие методы.
Как искать замену им? В доках что-то не нахожу, может плохо ищу?

Comment: смотреть новые видео

Comment: Как заметил тролль выше, новые видео... более новые. А если серьёзно, то читать документацию. Или в гугле спросить.

Comment: какой то конкретный пример можете привести?

Comment: Не смотрите видеоуроки вообще, читайте новые книги, переходите на Swift.

Comment: Для большинства устаревших методов в описании метода есть указание нового имени. Для оставшегося 1% прийдется немного погуглить. Для каких методов ты не нашел замену?

Comment: Для всех устаревших методов в документации Apple указан новый метод.

Comment: @Валентин willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:, но я вроде нашел viewWillTransitionToSize: